# Gitlab all pages history

Tags: github, gitlab, wiki

In Github, /wiki/_history link shows the history of all pages in wiki at one place. Currently Gitlab only displays history of individual pages under the "Page History"  eg. /wikis/Home/history. Is it possible to display global history in Gitlab like it is displayed in Github ?